# Meteor HTTP call loads image constantly

Tags: javascript, json, image, meteor

In my Meteor app, I am trying to load a random image from this API and I get a JSON like:

```
{
 "id":2026
 "url": "https:// ... " ,
 "large_url":null,
 "source_id":609,
 "copyright":"CC0",
 "site":"unsplash"
}
```

I do it this way:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.body.helpers({
        randomImage: function() {
            Meteor.call("unImage", function(error, results) {
                Session.set('url', results.data.url);
            });
            return Session.get('url');
       }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        unImage: function() {
            this.unblock();
            return Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://www.splashbase.co/api/v1/images/random");
        }
    });
}
```

In my html:

```
<div class="header" style="background-image: url('{{randomImage}}')">
  ...
</div>
```

This is working, but it *reloads* the image every second - more or less. I guess this is happening because the function `unImage`, which is on server side, loads all along with the server or something like that (not sure); anyway I cannot make it stop. Any ideas on how to solve it? And why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because session variable inside of your `randomImage` helper.
And [Session variables](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session) are reactive in nature, in which it re-runs in a block whenever its value is changed.

In this case, helper code is re-running again and again and hence, Meteor methods gets called again and again

So, move `Meteor.call` in helper to rendered event as shown below

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.body.rendered= function(){
       Meteor.call("unImage", function(error, results) {
          Session.set('url', results.data.url);
       });
    }


    Template.body.helpers({
        randomImage: function() {
            return Session.get('url');
       }
    });
}
```

Which should call the Meteor method once template is ready and setting `url` variable and thus reactively helper `randomImage` gets re-run and gets value of same

Comment: Maybe add that Reactive variables are re-run in reactive blocks, and that helpers happen to be some of it?

Comment: Great! Makes total sense! Thanks :)